# I have a string whose content is a function name, how to refer to the corresponding function in Python?

Tags: python, string, function, string-evaluation

For example, if I have a function called `add` like

```
def add(x,y):
    return x+y
```

and I want the ability to convert a string or an input to direct to that function like

```
w=raw_input('Please input the function you want to use')
```

or

```
w='add'
```

Is there any way to use w to refer to the function `add`?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Since you are taking user input, the safest way is to define exactly what is valid input:

```
dispatcher={'add':add}
w='add'
try:
    function=dispatcher[w]
except KeyError:
    raise ValueError('invalid input')
```

If you want to evaluate strings like `'add(3,4)'`, you could use [safe eval](http://lybniz2.sourceforge.net/safeeval.html):

```
eval('add(3,4)',{'__builtins__':None},dispatcher)
```

`eval` in general could be dangerous when applied to user input. <strike>The above is safer since `__builtins__` is disabled and `locals` is restricted to `dispatcher`. Someone cleverer than I might be able to still cause trouble, but I couldn't tell you how to do it.</strike>

**WARNING:** Even `eval(..., {'__builtins__':None}, dispatcher)` is **unsafe** to be applied to user input. A malicious user [could run arbitrary functions on your machine](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html) if given the opportunity to have his string evaluated by `eval`.

Comment: How about using what this answer(https://stackoverflow.com/a/22021058/9024698)  suggests?

Answer (score 21):

One safe way is to map from names to functions. It's safer than using `eval`.

```
function_mappings = {
        'add': add,
}

def select_function():
    while True:
        try:
            return function_mappings[raw_input('Please input the function you want to use')]
        except KeyError:
            print 'Invalid function, try again.'
```

Comment: Chris, when I add this to my code, I either get `NameError: name 'add' is not defined` or if I do `self.add()` (the full function call) then my code reads and executes the function when it's trying to read in the dictionary! Any thoughts on how to get this to work?

Comment: @Acoustic77: that’s a completely distinct matter, to do with methods. The question assumed a standalone function, `def add(x, y): …`. `add(1, 2)` would be a call, so `add` gets you the callable object (a function), which you can then call with `x(1, 2)`. If you want it to be a method instead, where you’d write `self.add(1, 2)`, then `self.add` gets you the callable object (a bound method), and `x(1, 2)` will call it. If you write `{'add': self.add()}`, those parentheses signify that you called the function, rather than simply referring to it as `{'add': self.add}` would do.

Comment: @Acoustic77: BTW, your question would be better as another question rather than a comment on an existing answer.

Comment: How about using what this answer(https://stackoverflow.com/a/22021058/9024698)  suggests?

Comment: If you don't want to use your own dictionary mapping, then you could use `global()`

Answer (score 18):

unutbu's solution is what I would normally use, but for completeness sake:

If you are specifying the exact name of the function, you can use `eval`, although it is highly discouraged because people can do malicious things:

```
eval("add")(x,y)
```

Answer (score 17):

[The built-in function `eval`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#eval) will do what you want. All the usual warnings about executing arbitrary user-supplied code apply.

If there are a finite number of predefined functions, you should avoid `eval` and use a lookup table instead (i.e. `Dict`). Never trust your users.

Answer (score 17):

Just use function reference:

```
def pwr(x, y):
    return x ** y

def add(x, y):
    return x + y

dispatcher = { 'pwr' : pwr, 'add' : add}

def call_func(x, y, func):
    try:
        return dispatcher[func](x, y)
    except:
        return "Invalid function"

call_func(2, 3, 'add')
```

Simple and secure.

Comment: That's very neat  How would you cater for differing number of arguments in the functions though?

Comment: @JohnCurry probably `call_func(func, *args, **kwargs):` ... `dispatcher[func](*args, **kwargs)`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76095609/6243352).

Answer (score 5):

If you are implementing a shell-like application where the user enter some command (such as **add**), and the application responses (return the sum), you can use the `cmd` module, which handles all the command interactions and dispatching for you. Here is an example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import cmd
import shlex
import sys

class MyCmd(cmd.Cmd):
    def do_add(self, arguments):
        '''add - Adds two numbers the print the sum'''
        x, y = shlex.split(arguments)
        x, y = int(x), int(y)
        print x + y

    def do_quit(self, s):
        '''quit - quit the program'''
        sys.exit(0)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    cmd = MyCmd()
    cmd.cmdloop('type help for a list of valid commands')
```

Here is a sample running session:

> $ python cmd_tryout.py
>   type help for a list of valid commands
>   (Cmd) **help add**
>   add - Adds two numbers the print the sum
>   (Cmd) **add 5 3**
>   8
>   (Cmd) **quit**

At the prompt *(Cmd)*, you can issue the `help` command which you get for free. Other commands are `add` and `quit` which correspond to the `do_add()` and `do_quit()` functions.

Note that help command displays the docstring for your function. The docstring is a string immediately follows the function declararation (see `do_add()` for example).

The `cmd` module does not do any argument spliting, parsing, so you have to do it yourself. The `do_add()` function illustrates this.

This sample program should be enough to get you started. For more information look up the [cmd](http://docs.python.org/2/library/cmd.html) help page. It is trivia to customize the prompt and other aspect of your program.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem.

The way I recommend you to handle it is to create a temporary Python file to store the function the user input. Here's an example I used in a program I wrote to draw representations of mathematical functions:

```
with open("function.py",'w') as file:
    f=input('enter the function you want to draw example: 2*x+1 or e**x :\n')
    file.write("from math import *\ndef f(x):\n\treturn "+f)
```

This will create a file containing the function I want to call.

Next, you must call the function you wrote in the file to your program:

```
from function import f
```

Now you can use your function as normal python function.

If you want, you can also delete the file where you stored your function using os.remove:

```
import os
os.remove("function.py")
```

To help you understand, here is my program to draw mathematical functions:

```
import numpy
import cv2
import os
from math import *


def generate(f,a,b,min,max,functionname='noname'):
    ph=(b-a)/1920
    pv=(max-min)/1080
    picture=numpy.zeros((1080,1920))
    for i in range(0,1920):
        picture[1079-(int((f(a+(i+1)*ph)*1080/max))),i]=255
    for i in range(1920):
        picture[1079-(int((f(a+(i+1)*ph)*1080/max)))+1,i]=255
    cv2.imwrite(functionname+'.png',picture)


with open("function.py",'w') as file:
    f=input('enter the function you want to draw example: or e**x :\n')
    file.write("from math import *\ndef f(x):\n\treturn "+f)

from function import f
os.remove("function.py")
d=input('enter the interval ,min ,max and the image file name. Separate characters with spacebar. Example: 0 1 0 14 exponontielle :\n').split(" ")
generate(f,int(d[0]),int(d[1]),int(d[2]),int(d[3]),d[4])
```

Answer (score 3):

```
def add(x,y):
  print(x+y)

def subtract(x,y):
  print(x-y)

function_list = {'add', 'subtract'}

def caller(func, x, y):
  
  eval(func)(x,y) # more security exploits
  
  if func in function_list:
    eval(func)(x,y) # less security exploits

caller("add", 1, 2)
```

Answer (score 2):

I've had many situation where I've needed to compare a string to an int and vice versa within a Django template.

I created a filter that allowed me to pass in the function name and using eval() convert it.

Example:

Template:

```
{% ifequal string int|convert:'str' %} do something {% endifequal %}
```

Template Filter (where i use a string to call the function name):

```
@register.filter
def convert(value, funcname):
    try:
        converted = eval(funcname)(value)
        return converted
    except:
        return value
```

Answer (score 1):

With reference to John Curry's question above ... if you want a version of Jefferson Felix's code that handles multiple arguments, then the simplest solution is to provide the arguments in a list, and arrange for each of the dispatched functions to check the argument count before proceeding.

A simple version that I've just tested in Visual Studio code is as follows:

```
import math

def sin(args):
    argc = len(args)
    if (argc == 1):
        result = math.sin(args[0])
    else:
        result = None

    return(result)

def sum(args):
    argc = len(args)
    if (argc == 2):
        result = args[0] + args[1]
    else:
        result = None

    return(result)


def dot_product(args):
    argc = len(args)
    if (argc == 2):
        vector1 = args[0]
        vector2 = args[1]
        if (len(vector1) == 3 and len(vector2) == 3):
            result = (vector1[0] * vector2[0]) + (vector1[1] * vector2[1]) + (vector1[2] * vector2[2])
        else:
            result = None
    else:
        result = None

    return(result)

dispatcher = {"sin" : sin, "sum" : sum, "dot_product" : dot_product}

def call_func(dispatcher, func_name, args):
    func_list = list(dispatcher.keys())
    if (func_list.count(func_name) == 0):
        return(None)
    else:
        return(dispatcher[func_name](args))

val = call_func(dispatcher, "sin", [0.6])
print(f"Sine is : {val}")

val = call_func(dispatcher, "sum", [4, 6])
print(f"sum is : {val}")

val = call_func(dispatcher, "dot_product", [[3, 7, 2], [5, 9, 4]])
print(f"dot product is : {val}")
```

The output looks as follows:

```
Sine is : 0.5646424733950354
sum is : 10
dot product is : 86
```

Of course, a more sophisticated version would include better error trapping that simply returning "None" if an error is found, but the above can be used as a template to build upon. Likewise, the dot_product function could be improved to handle vectors of any dimension, but I leave that as an exercise for the reader ...

Answer (score 0):

[I got here via a duplicate question. My first thought was to use `argparse` and `shlex` and I didn't see that here, so I'm adding it as another option.]

You could use `argparse` to set up a registry of functions/commands and safely parse their args. This will provide some level of user-friendliness too by, e.g., letting you know when you've entered a command that doesn't exist.

```
import argparse
import shlex

def hello(name):
    print('hello,', name)

def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    subparsers = parser.add_subparsers()

    hello_parser = subparsers.add_parser('hello')
    hello_parser.add_argument('name')
    hello_parser.set_defaults(func=hello)

    print('Enter q to quit')

    while True:
        command = input('command> ')
        command = command.strip()

        if not command:
            continue

        if command.lower() == 'q':
            break

        words = shlex.split(command)

        try:
            args = parser.parse_args(words)
        except SystemExit:
            # argparse will sys.exit() on -h and errors; prevent that
            continue

        func_args = {name: value for name, value in vars(args).items()}
        del func_args['func']
        args.func(**func_args)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        main()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print()
```

Answer (score 0):

This question belongs to an arcane Python era obviously, but I thought this might be useful for people getting here from search engines..

Nowadays, you can do something like this (no manual mappings required):

```
func = locals()[ name ]
print( f'Found local function {func}' )
func()
```

Of course, for any real use case you should check that you actually found anything before executing it!

Answer (score 0):

To generalize and improve on [these](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7719486/6243352) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51456172/6243352):

```py
import operator


def foo():
    return "foo called"


def bar(x, y):
    return "bar called with args", x, y


def baz(x, kwarg=42):
    return "baz called with args", x, kwarg


callables = {
    "foo": foo,
    "bar": bar,
    "baz": baz,
    "add": operator.add,
}
def call(func_name, *args, **kwargs):
    return callables[func_name](*args, **kwargs)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(call("foo"))  # => foo called
    print(*call("bar", 1, 2))  # => bar called with args 1 2
    print(*call("baz", 3, kwarg=42))  # => baz called with args 3 42
    print(call("add", 4, 5))  # => 9
```

In general, use the `*args, **kwargs` idiom for any situation where you want to pass arbitrary arguments to a wrapped function.

It's better to raise if the function isn't present rather than return a random magic string, preferably with a custom error like `FunctionNotCallable` so it can be differentiated from return values and errors from the functions you're calling.

For OP's use case, as you can see, the `operator` library already has functional versions of operators.