# NameError: x is not defined

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to make a simple plotting function `plot2d`,

```
def plot2d(xmin,xmax,func): 

    x=np.linspace(xmin, xmax, num=50)    

    plt.plot(x,func)
    plt.show()
```

The idea is you input the variable 'func' in terms of x, like x**2.

edit* 
Here's the error:

```
>>> plot2d(-10,10, x**2)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'x' is not defined
```

edit**
I think the issue was that when you first call the function the linspace x hasn't be created yet. This worked:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def plot2d(xmin,xmax): 
x=np.linspace(xmin, xmax, num=50)    

func=input('Define fucntion: ')
plt.plot(x,func)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Show us how you call your `plot2d`, and show the traceback of the error plz.

Comment: Aren't you supposed to pass `x` as an argument to `func`?

Answer (score 4):

You might want to learn about [`lambda`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#lambda). Change your code a bit would suffice:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def plot2d(xmin,xmax,func): 

    x=np.linspace(xmin, xmax, num=50)    

    plt.plot(x,func(x)) #func -> func(x)
    plt.show()

#pass a unnamed lambda as a param: 
plot2d(-10, 10, lambda x: x*x)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from pylab import *

def plot2d(xmin, xmax, func):
    x=np.linspace(xmin,xmax,num=50)
    y=func(x)
    plot(x,y)
    show()

def func(x):
    y=x**2
    return y

plot2d(0,10,func)
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: My hope was to be able define any functions. TBH I was going for something resembling mathematicas plot function.

Comment: @user3556814, Taking function from user as input deviates from the scope of this thread. You might want to refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7719466/how-to-convert-a-string-to-a-function-in-python