# How to convert a string to a class name?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

I checked [I have a string whose content is a function name, how to refer to the corresponding function in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7719466/how-to-convert-a-string-to-a-function-in-python) but it is not the question I want to ask.

The question is: I have a string `'ABC'` and I want to create an instance of class `ABC` as:

```
my_obj = ABC ()
```

The input `'ABC'` is read from Python arguments (`argparse`).

The class is already defined and imported.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dictionary:

```
d = {'ABC': ABC}  # where ABC is the class object

my_obj = d['ABC']()
```

This should be preferable to solutions using `global` (poor practice) and `eval` (security risks).

This may seem cumbersome until you realise that classes and class instances are first class objects in Python. You should never rely on evaluating strings to call a Python object. Be explicit, even if it's not elegant.