# passing a keyword to method to print its __doc__ in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def docstring(fname):
    print(fname.__doc__)

fname = input()
docstring(fname)
```

Given input:

```
print
```

The question is about to print the `__doc__` of the `print` keyword, but here we can get output directly by command (`print.__doc__`) but while passing the variable (`fname`) to a function (`docstring`) and from there printing `__doc__` showing different result as it is showing doc of variable but I need the doc of value in the variable.

**Showing output:**

> str(object='') -> str str(bytes_or_buffer[, encoding[, errors]]) ->
> str
>
> Create a new string object from the given object. If encoding or
> errors is specified, then the object must expose a data buffer that
> will be decoded using the given encoding and error handler. Otherwise,
> returns the result of object.**str**() (if defined) or repr(object).
> encoding defaults to sys.getdefaultencoding(). errors defaults to
> 'strict'.

**Required output**

> print(value, ..., sep=' ', end='\n', file=sys.stdout,
> flush=False)\n\nPrints the values to a stream, or to sys.stdout by
> default.\nOptional keyword arguments:\nfile:  a file-like object
> (stream); defaults to the current sys.stdout.\nsep:   string inserted
> between values, default a space.\nend:   string appended after the
> last value, default a newline.\nflush: whether to forcibly flush the
> stream

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert a string to a function name in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7719466/how-to-convert-a-string-to-a-function-name-in-python)

Comment: Hum... makes sens to me. Could you explain more why you didn't expect this output ?

Comment: If you only expect to get built-in functions as input you can do `__builtins__[fname].__doc__`

Comment: `fname` is just a string (the result of the `input()` call). This is why you get the doc of string. If you want to convert the string to the actual function object (in order to get the doc), see the link or my suggestion above

Comment: Thank you so much @Tomerikoo

Answer (score 0):

Use eval to get the right doc string printed.

```
def docstring(fname):
    return eval(fname + '.__doc__')

print(docstring('print'))
```